# Multiple select with custom data

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a form with a multiple select like this:

```
.form-row__select
        = f.collection_check_boxes(:game_ids, @games, :id, :name)
```

The collection @games worked because the data was returned this way:

```
=> #<Game:0x00007fa12c3a9560
 id: 5,
 name: :example,
 active: true,
 ...
```

But now I need to add custom data to my collection and I was not able to make the multiple select work:

```
game = Game.enabled.includes(:category)
    @games = game.map do |s|
       [[s.category.name, I18n.t(s.type_code, scope: 'enum.type.name')].join(' - '), s.id]
    end
@games.sort!
```

The result of the above method is an array of array like this:

```
[["Example one - Category X", 5],
["Example four - Category Y", 1]]
...
```

How can I make a multiple select using the array above and showing its strings so they can be selected?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def my_fancy_pants_name
    [s.category.name, I18n.t(s.type_code, scope: 'enum.type.name')].join(' - ')
  end
end
```

```
.form-row__select
   = f.collection_check_boxes(:game_ids, @games, :id, :my_fancy_pants_name, multiple: true)
```

If you're bothered by putting this logic in the model you can go with a decorator. You can also pass a block to customize the input and label further as detailed [in the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I was able to add the method to model as you suggested and it worked. However, I am having another problem right now: I can't seem to order the strings that were returned. I need to put them into alphabetical order. Previously I was able to do that because I used to map all of them and put a 'sort' at the end of the method, as you can see in the example above. Would you please have any suggestion as to how I can put them into order? Thank you so so much.

Comment: @games.sort(&:my_fancy_pants_name)